# Eval alternative for rubocop

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir, rubocop

I have the following method:

```
def expect_url_to_end_with_string(*args)
 method_string = 'expect(driver.url).to end_with(url_str)'.dup
 args.each do |arg|
   method_string.concat(" | end_with(\'#{arg}\')")
 end
 eval method_string
end
```

Rubocop is complaining about eval method. Is there an alternative? Can I for example create main proc `{ expect(driver.url).to end_with(url_str) }` andproc `{| end_with(arg)}?` for each arg and concatenate them?

Comment: Just for curiosity: why did you decide to use eval and not a custom RSpec matcher?

Comment: This is a base Page Object class. Page objects uses the method to check if URL string matches string defined by us. Sometimes they need to check more than one string, so I wanted to pass them as arguments to build more conditions. Instead base expect(driver.url).to end_with(url_str), I check expect(driver.url).to end_with(url_str) | end_with(arg). The number of conditions can vary, so I decided to build the string adding conditions and then execute the code using eval.

Comment: I mean what you are doing here is building a custom expectation dynamically. But there is another way to achieve this (in most cases in a cleaner and more maintainable way, with cleaner error reports etc) - custom RSpec matches. You could have something like `expect(driver.url).to end_with_any_of_strings(*args)` where `end_with_any_of_strings` is your custom matcher that performs the necessary check and produces a nice error message for better testing experience...